# Swagger UI and ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, swagger

Does Service Stack support Models in Swagger. 
In the sample code below

```
[Route("/User", "GET", Summary = "Get all the users available")]
[Route("/User", "POST, PUT", Summary = "Create a new user")]
[Route("/User/{Id}", "GET", Summary = "Get user with a specific id")]
public class User : RequestBase, IReturn<UserResponse>
{
    [ApiMember(Name = "Id", Description = "The User Id", ParameterType = "path", DataType = "int", IsRequired = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Name = "UserData", Description = "The User Data", ParameterType = "body", DataType = "complex", IsRequired = false)]
    public UserData Entry { get; set; }
}
```

I would like UserData to be a complex type or container type. However if I define it to be one of these, all I get in the SwaggerUI is a text area box. I do not get the Model and ModelSchema links that I see in the petstore example online.

http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/#!/pet/addPet_post_1

Answer (score 1):

Parameters of type "body" are properly supported as of the latest ServiceStack releases. You will need to set `DataType = "User"` in your second `ApiMember` attribute. This will allow the Swagger UI to correctly display model schema information. Also, for simple types, you can use constants in the `SwaggerType` class; for example you can change the first `Apimember` attribute to have `DataType = SwaggerType.Int`.